# Duvida sobre shell script

Tags: linux, script, shell, terminal

Estou estudando linux, e é meu primeiro contato com o shell script, a documentação que eu queria fazer é a seguinte:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ uname - m = "x86_64" ]; then
  echo "sua versão é de 64bits"
else
  echo "sua versão é de 32bits"
fi
```

tentei usar esta que fiz, mas não está funcionando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem que dar uma lida em como funciona a comparação em Shell, ele não aceita somente colocar o comando direto na comparação.

O que você deve fazer é guardar o valor em uma variável e depois comparar essa variável com o valor que você quer:

```
#!/bin/bash

resultado=`uname -m`
if [ $resultado = "x86_64" ]; then
  echo "sua versão é de 64bits"
else
  echo "sua versão é de 32bits"
fi
```

Obs: como você pode ver, para executar um comando e guardar ele em uma variável, é necessário utilizar o acento grave (``) e colocar o comando dentro.

Answer (score 0):

Ou poderia utilizar o novo padrão adotado!:

```
resultado = $(uname -m)
```

Answer (score 0):

A resposta aceita apesar de funcionar está **equivocada** ao afirmar que:

> ele não aceita somente colocar o comando direto na comparação

Podemos sim passar o comando diretamente na condicional, vejamos como fica:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(uname -m) == "x86_64" ]]; then
  echo "sua versão é de 64bits"
else
  echo "sua versão é de 32bits"
fi
```

Portanto, `$(uname -m)` executará o comando e incluirá sua saída na condição `if` que irá comparar a igualdade, note que estou usando `[[ ... ]]`, isso porque o operador de colchetes duplos é utilizado para comparação de strings entre outras coisas, ele é uma versão melhorada dos colchetes simples no entanto tem a desvantagem de que seu script deve ser específico do bash.